# Can an extension be made to interact with a floating/dockable window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx

Is it possible to create an extension that interacts with a floating/dockable window in VS2010? If so, are there any code samples that could demonstrate this?

At the very least could I create a XAML markup to *look* like a floating window is docked to the view somewhere?

Thanks,
   Nick

Comment: Do you mean creating a tool window?  I'm pretty sure there is a template for that that comes with the SDK, and you can download the [tool windows sample here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ToolWindows).